# What is the location of this Windows 10 wallpaper?

Tags: where-on-earth, lock-screens, canadian-rockies

[image]

Saw this from Windows 10 wallpaper. Hope that someone can help find this - blue lake with snowy mountain. I want to go here one day! Looks very serene.

Comment: Probably Banff or Jasper parks

Comment: Anecdote: there is a motorcyclists who makes vlogs I watch from Alberta; he gets drone shots of Lake Louise all the time. It is simply the most beautiful scenery (to me) I have ever seen.

Comment: Video of a wedding at the Lake Louise: https://youtu.be/ok6L6rvquCE?t=9s

Comment: Just for your information - there is a website exactly designed for such problems: http://where-is-this.com :)

Answer (score 43):

The picture is from Lake [Louise](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/pn-np/ab/banff/visit/les10-top10/louise.aspx#parking) in [Banff](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Banff) National Park in Alberta, Canada, in the Canadian Rockies. That view is probably from the [Fairmont](http://www.fairmont.com/lake-louise/media/photos/) hotel.

It's one of the top nature destinations in Canada and if you're interested in visiting, they're open pretty much all year round though to get that view you have to go in summer.

[image]

Comment: "arguably easier" → "essential"

Comment: @gerrit yup, fixed. Can't find a proper rights free picture of the lake :-/

Comment: Try advanced google images search by copyright status.  See also [this answer on Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/7628/1033).

Comment: Not sure how work summer on Canada because I live on the equator meridian and only know rain/dry season. But wont you need winter to see the snow on the mountain?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it's a glacial lake, the water comes from a glacier which is solid even in summer (though it gains volume in winter). Check out Lefroy Glacier

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Also, even at lower latitudes mountain peaks can remain snow-covered year round.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: If you travel high enough, it doesn't really matter what time of year it is - it'll be cold and the pressure will be low. -> Snow!

Answer (score 12):

Since someone wondered if it could be winter in one of the comments, here is what winter looks like
[image]

Comment: That looks like fun.